# bash: node: command not found, but full path is working; how can I make just "node -v" work? (node.js)

Tags: node.js, windows, path

I just installed node.js. I tried to make sure it was installed by running 'node -v' but got the error "bash: node: command not found." I checked some answers here, and when I put in the full path "c:/dev/www.tctmd.com/node -v" it worked.

What I want to know is how do I fix it so that I can just type in "node" instead of "c:/dev/www.tctmd.com/node"? I'm currently in the /www.tctmd.com folder in my command shell. Using Windows 7.

Comment: How did you install it? The installer should install it to a standard directory (not that one) and add it to PATH.

Comment: I used the Windows 64x installer from nodejs.org. I specified a location to install it into, because I was told that I needed to put it into the same folder as my website, the www.tctmd.com folder, so I'm not sure if that's the problem. Other than that I just did a standard installation

Comment: You do not need to put it in the same folder (deployment is a separate story, and depends on your host / servers).  You should run the installer normally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash: npm: command not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585029/bash-npm-command-not-found)

Answer (score 6):

This is really stupid but it turns out I just need to close and reopen my command line.

Comment: Lol tnx. Same problem was for me. :D