# bash: npm: command not found?

Tags: node.js, windows

I'm learning laravel and follwing this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLillGF-RfqbYhQsN5WMXy6VsDMKGadrJ-),

But when I went try and install npm, is says `bash: npm: command not found`

[image]

Comment: You need to install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/es/) first

Comment: this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472755/sudo-npm-command-not-found

Comment: It seems that `npm` (Node Packet Manager) isn't installed. It could be resolved by installing **[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)**

Comment: I just did `npm update -g` ... after which npm vanished and got `-bash: npm: command not found`. wtf?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am following the same tuturial and I had this issue and how I solved is just download the

### 8.11.4 LTS version

from [this link](https://nodejs.org/en/) then install it then the command worked just fine!

Comment: My problem was that I did not install the node.js, all you need to do for this is to just install node.js - [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm)

Comment: Exactly, That is what I meant by installing the 8.11.4 LTS version.

Comment: In my case isn't owrking...

Answer (score 33):

If you have already installed nodejs and still getting this error. npm: command not found..

run this

```
apt-get install -y npm
```

Comment: Don't forget to sudo!

Comment: yeah but what if you're using `git bash`

Comment: If you're using GitBash, exit first, the open it again and try to run `npm -v` after installing from the npmjs site (its already one package -nodejs and -npm).

Comment: Question has tag "windows" and you're giving linux commands.

Comment: This gave me old version on Ubuntu. So I followed the official guides to install node/npm - https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm

Answer (score 18):

I also come here for the same problem, The solution I found is to install [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) and then restart the Visual Studio Code

Comment: For people who wanna copy and paste the command, you install `npm` using `sudo apt-get install -y npm`.

Answer (score 8):

in redhat base OS (tested in centos 7)

```
yum install nodejs npm -y
```

in debian base OS

```
apt-get install -y npm
```

Comment: This worked for me on a centos server with cpanel. Thanks man ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I know it's an old question. But it keeps showing in google first position and all it says it's "install node.js". 
For a newbie this is not obvious, so all you have to do is go to the node.js website and search for the command for your linux distribution version or any other operating system. Here is the link: 
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

In this page you have to choose your operating system and you'll find your command. Then you just log into your console as a root (using putty for instance) and execute that command.

After that, you log as normal user and go again inside your laravel application folder and run again npm install command, and it should work. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the real answer for this issue. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple.

After installing Node, you should restart your VScode and run npm install command.

Comment: After trying so many things (I'd already installed npm/Node), it was as simple as making sure I'd shut down VSCode and then reopening it. It worked in Terminal after then.

Answer (score 3):

If you already installed **[npm](https://npmjs.com)** globally on your system, and you are still getting the above error message by using **VSCode terminal**. Just close your **VSCode application** and reopen again, that should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

First You need to check the node version using terminal (not gitbash)

```
node --version

npm --version
```

if those exists, Restart your pc and check

Cheers !!

Comment: This is working perfectly for me....

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was entirely my fault (as usual) I was changing the system path under the environment variables, in Windows, and messed up the path for Node/NPM. So the solution is to either re-add the path for NPM, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27864253/7443287)
or the lazy option: re-install it which will re-add it for you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe vscode config shell failed, you can try restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change to zsh.
Write in command line `zsh` , then again `npm i`.